# Why do I get Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datagrid, aspxgridview

So I'm making a SQL Query that takes up to 10 mins to retrieve about 20K data elements. That itself has no problem, as I am able to set breakpoint and look at the information retrieved and display them in a DataGrid, and no error occurs.... apparently.

However, on the displayed website I see no elements on that DataGrid and when I go to the developer tool's console I see

**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.**

I've been looking online for a response regarding this error, and I've seen that it could be a timeout on the consult, however I am able to see the data after it gets retrieved so it looks more like an issue with the DataGrid component. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm making a SQL Query that takes up to 10 mins to retrieve about 20K data elements. That itself has no problem

This is a problem in itself. Likely the Server will cancel the connection after 0.5-5 minutes. And from experience, it is also a useless amount of data to retreive.

No human will be able to process **20000 records** in any meaningfull way. You have to apply further filtering, before you got any chance of showing that to a user. If the user can process 200 entries, that would be 1% of what you retreived. And it will be likely less then that - I would guess for maybe 20.

It is a very common beginners mistake to retreive a ton from the DB, then do filtering in the code. Thgat will really just waste RAM, CPU cycles and Network Bandwidth on something the DB server was better at to begin with. This is even worse for WebServers, wich really have no memory or CPU cycles to spare.

Do as much filtering, ordering, pagination and even processing in the query itself.